# Python get RandomX hashes

Tags: python

I am currently trying to use [pyrx](https://github.com/jtgrassie/pyrx) to build an XMR miner in Python. However, this library does not appear to support Windows. Does anyone have any solutions to get RandomX hashes in python on windows?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably you've tried and succeeded with the latest version as you've now moved onto using monero-powpy in a [later question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/13491/how-to-make-monero-powpy-compatable-with-xmrig-proxy-running-in-nicehash-mode) (which includes pyrx)? If so, please answer your own question.