# How to make monero-powpy compatable with xmrig-proxy running in 'nicehash' mode?

Tags: mining, python

I know I have to somehow implement [this spec](https://github.com/nicehash/Specifications/blob/master/NiceHash_CryptoNight_modification_v1.0.txt) but other than that I'm not sure.

Any help/resources is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd modify `def pack_nonce` to account for the Nicehash nonce byte. I.e. only pack 3 bytes.

E.g.

```
diff --git a/stratum-miner.py b/stratum-miner.py
index 486e877..ec3ae5f 100644
--- a/stratum-miner.py
+++ b/stratum-miner.py
@@ -99,8 +99,8 @@ def main():
 def pack_nonce(blob, nonce):
     b = binascii.unhexlify(blob)
     bin = struct.pack('39B', *bytearray(b[:39]))
-    bin += struct.pack('I', nonce)
-    bin += struct.pack('{}B'.format(len(b)-43), *bytearray(b[43:]))
+    bin += struct.pack('I', nonce & 0x00ffffff)[:3]
+    bin += struct.pack('{}B'.format(len(b)-42), *bytearray(b[42:]))
     return bin
 
 
@@ -146,6 +146,7 @@ def worker(q, s):
                 elapsed = time.time() - started
                 hr = int(hash_count / elapsed)
                 print('{}Hashrate: {} H/s'.format(os.linesep, hr))
+                nonce = struct.unpack('I', bin[39:43])[0]
                 submit = {
                     'method':'submit',
                     'params': {
```

Or simply using the [latest version](https://github.com/jtgrassie/monero-powpy/blob/master/stratum-miner.py) with the `--nicehash` flag.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I knew it was something to do with pack_nonce, I'm just not sure how exactly to implement utilizing the given Nicehash nonce byte, regardless, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @PGBRULES you would *implement* like: https://paste.debian.net/1229411/

Comment: did that code work for you when you tested with any xmrig-proxy pool in nicehash mode? For me, once I changed the nonce on line 158 to just send the raw nonce instead of what was there before, I only got low difficulty share errors. I'm mining on a 9900K. 
Line before: `'nonce': binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('<I', nonce)).decode(),`                                Line after: `'nonce': nonce,`

Comment: Also had to change the nonce equals line to `nonce = struct.unpack('I', bin[40:44])[0]`

Comment: Which is what I just showed you in https://paste.debian.net/1229411/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that? In that paste you had bin[40,44] which produces a type error. As for my first comment: In the paste you didn't change the nonce when it was being submitted, you kept the hexify and decode part. I changed it submit the nonce as determined by struct.unpack.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You literally just commented with lines I wrote which you're saying you changed to?! And bin[40:44] is not a type error.

Comment: `+                nonce = struct.unpack('I', bin[40,44])[0]` is what you posted. I changed this to `bin[40:44]` as otherwise it produces a type error. In addition, I said in the submit field, you forgot to change it from the binascii.hexlify code to just passing the raw nonce.

Comment: I didn't *forget* to change it, it shouldn't need changing.

Comment: Of course it needs changing? `'nonce': binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('<I', nonce)).decode()` wouldn't work when the nonce is an integer? `nonce = struct.unpack('I', bin[40:44])[0]`

Comment: Of course it works. You are pack'ing and integer to binary then converting to a hex string.

Comment: Well then it's something with that because when using the original nonce submission code(` 'nonce': binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('<I', nonce)).decode()`),  I get an "Invalid nonce; is miner not compatible with NiceHash?" error which I don't get if I just send the nonce without hexifying it.

Comment: The nonce is *always* a hex string, even with NiceHash.

Comment: Well changing that line to just pass the `struct.unpack('I', bin[40:44])[0]` removes the nicehash compatibility error and instead just creates a new error of a low difficulty share error.

Comment: change bin[40:44] to bin[39:43] I've just done, tested and validated as working: https://paste.debian.net/1229411/